# OverallStatus Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api

Based on [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150456/marketing-cloud-rest-api-show-list-of-data-extension) I a trying to get a list of my Salesforce Marketing Cloud DataExtensions using the following XML in SoapUI (auth added automatically)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <RetrieveRequest>
              <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
              <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
              <Properties>Name</Properties>
              <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
           </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Whatever I do, the response has the very helpful OverallStatus message 'Error'. No error code or description.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>QueryResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:08402dfb-1b44-413a-b474-cdbaa276cdea</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:ba4a56e6-3116-4cc0-b1e4-1719f07e83cb</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-943ea217-eb5d-4b5a-b041-78434f5ab20a">
            <wsu:Created>2018-02-08T18:12:13Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2018-02-08T18:17:13Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <QueryResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
         <RequestID>f3dd242f-0843-4203-adae-71264a7a815c</RequestID>
      </QueryResponseMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Any way to get a more expressive error message? `Error` is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK sorted. Cause: User error.

I didn't understand that the 'folders' in SoapUI have significance. They set the `SOAPAction` header. I'd put my `RetrieveRequest` in the Query folder, when it needed to be the Retrieve folder.

[image: wrong folder in SoapUI]

Lesson learned!

Comment: Yes, if you do it in another app, ie: Postman, you need to add the header: SOAPAction:"Retrieve" in this case

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it using the fueloauth param, ie:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
   <soapenv:Header>
   <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">YOUR TOKEN</fueloauth>
  </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
            <Properties>Name</Properties>     
            <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>         
        </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I think you should add the header with the token or the username/token header:

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
             <wsse:Username>YOUR USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">YOUR PASSWORD_</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Trying your first code snippet using a token retrieved from the REST endpoint `/v1/requestToken` gives the same error for me shown in the question. The same when disabling SoapUI's Basic Authentication and using your second code snippet. Authentication looks to work both ways, so are there additional permissions needed?

Comment: Are you giving permissions over Data Extension > Read to your "API Integration" component?